# Docker compose error with hue and mysql - 1130, "Host '172.20.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I need help to connect hue with my database. When I run docker-compose up, the hue down/fail.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  hue:
    image: hue
    hostname: hue
    container_name: hue
    dns: 8.8.8.8
    ports:
    - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./data/hue/hue-overrides.ini:/usr/share/hue/desktop/conf/z-hue.ini
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500m

  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    hostname: database
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500m
    command: mysqld --innodb-flush-method=O_DSYNC --innodb-use-native-aio=OFF --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
        - ./data/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./data/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: hue
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
```

**Docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                    NAMES
41a3cbb80704   mysql           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp, :::33061->3306/tcp   database
```

**Log:**

```
hue                          | [02/Oct/2022 13:34:51 -0700] decorators   INFO     Using django-axes 2.2.0
hue                          | Traceback (most recent call last):
hue                          |   File "./build/env/bin/hue", line 11, in <module>
hue                          |     load_entry_point('desktop', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 225, in entry
hue                          |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
hue                          |     utility.execute()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
hue                          |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
hue                          |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
hue                          |     self.check()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
hue                          |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
hue                          |     issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
hue                          |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
hue                          |     issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
hue                          |     issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
hue                          |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
hue                          |     return self._cursor()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
hue                          |     self.ensure_connection()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
hue                          |     self.connect()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
hue                          |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
hue                          |     self.connect()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
hue                          |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
hue                          |     conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
hue                          |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
hue                          |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
hue                          | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '172.21.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

**This is my local mysql:**

```
mysql> SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| %         |
| localhost |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**When I run** `docker exec -it database bash`:

```
$ docker exec -it database bash

root@database:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Screenshots are almost always the worst way to represent information, especially those that are too tiny to read.

Comment: Sorry I can fix it

Comment: You should have a `MYSQL_USER` that's something other than `root`, too, as `root` is already created by default.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is:

```
Host '172.21.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

So you have to create a new user and allow access from anywhere(%) and grant the necessary permissions to it:

```
CREATE USER 'hueuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysafepass';
CREATE USER 'hueuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysafepass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'hueuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'hueuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Same error `Host '172.23.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` :\

Comment: Did you change the username and password in the docker-compose file?

Comment: Yes -> MYSQL_ROOT_USER: myuser / MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass / MYSQL_DATABASE: hue / MYSQL_USER: myuser / MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass

Comment: MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
MYSQL_DATABASE: hue
MYSQL_USER: myuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass

and where the hue gets the new login details?

Comment: A config (.ini) file -> [[database]]
    host=database
    port=3306
    engine=mysql
    user=root
    password=secret
    name=hue

Comment: change the user to myuser and the pass to mypass

Comment: I have a folder with config files for my docker-compose and didn't have permission...

Solution: sudo chmod -R 777 ./folder

Thanks for your help